# jQuery load not populating select element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have code that when page loads, makes a call to mysql and populates a `select` element with data. This works fine on initial load or when I refresh the page, but what I am trying to do is, when I get a success callback from ajax, is to update or repopulate the `select` element with the new data.

I can see that the data is being returned from ajax in firebug, but for some reason, is not populating the `select` element. I would be grateful if someone could spot where I have messed up. Many thanks.

PHP / HTML code

```
<div class="fieldset">
            <h1><span>Select Your Box(es)</span></h1>
            <p>
              <select data-placeholder="Choose your box(es)..." class="chosen-select" name="box_frtv[]" id="box_frtv" multiple required="required">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php
                  do {

                  ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_rs_fbrtv['boxref']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_fbrtv['boxref']; ?></option>
                <?php
                  } while ($row_rs_fbrtv = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_fbrtv));

                  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_fbrtv);

                  if($rows > 0) {

                  mysql_data_seek($rs_fbrtv, 0);

                  $row_rs_fbrtv = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_fbrtv);

                  }

                  ?>
              </select><span></span><div id="boxError"></div>
            </p>
          </div>
```

jquery code

```
submitHandler: function ()
{
  if ($("#USRfilertv").valid() === true)
  {
    var data = $("#USRfilertv").serialize();

    $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "frtv.php",
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",

      success: function (data)
      {
        if (data.opp == 'error')
        {
          var messageOutput = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          {

            messageOutput += data[i].file + '  ';

          }

          notif({
            msg: "There was an error retrieving the following file: "  + '<br /><br />' + '<b><font color=\"black\">' + data.file + '</font></b><br /><br />' + ' Please correct this error and try again.<br />If this error persists, please contact us quoting ref: ' + '<b><font color=\"#fbf66a\">' + '#FRTV0001.<br />' + '</font>' + '<br />' + 'Thank you.',
            type: "frtvError",
            position: "center",
            width: 490,
            height: 75,
            multiline: true,
            timeout: 6000,
            opacity: 0.8,
            fade: 10,
        });
        }
        else
        {
          var messageOutputs = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          {

            messageOutputs += data[i].file + '  ';

          }

          $("#USRfilertv").get(0).reset();
          $("#box_frtv").load("refreshFrtv.php");
          $("#frtv_address").trigger("chosen:updated");

          notif({
            msg: "You have successfully retrieved the following file(s)."  + '<br /><br />' + '<b><font color=\"black\">' + data.file + '</font></b><br /><br />' + ' These file(s) were successfully entered into the database.<br />Thank you.',
            type: "FileRtvSuccess",
            position: "center",
            width: 440,
            height: 75,
            multiline: true,
            timeout: 6000,
            opacity: 0.8,
            fade: 10,
        });
        $("#box_frtv_chosen").find('option:selected').remove();
        $("#box_frtv").html('');
        $("#box_frtv").trigger("chosen:updated");
        $("#box_ffrtv_chosen").find('option:selected').remove();
        $("#box_ffrtv").html('');
        $("#box_ffrtv").trigger("chosen:updated");
        }

      }

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably your page is cached. I had a similar problem and I solved adding a new var with a current Date Time in my ajax call. I don't know if it can solve your problem.

Comment: Use .class instead #id for selectors... typical error

Comment: @Andrea could you expand on your answer please. Thanks

Comment: @Pirs Tried that Pirs but still the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repopulate the Options in the select you can (empty) the Options in the Select and (append) the new Options you create from the database.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/48v5ufca/

**Jquery**

```
$("#clickme").on("click", function(e) {
var messageOutputs = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {

            messageOutputs += '<option value="">New'+i+'</option>';


          }

$("#box_frtv").empty();
$("#box_frtv").append(messageOutputs);
});
```

Comment: The idea is that once a user has submitted successfully, the select is refreshed, in this case: refreshFrtv.php fetches the new data from mysql. I do not want an item selected just repopulate the select. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the Demo. That's what append does. Just take out the conditon (if (i != 3) { ...) and repopulate the Select as you like. Ill amend the answer

Comment: That is what the chosen plugin does. $("#box_frtv").trigger("chosen:updated"); so in essence, should work. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem using `$.get`.

I was trying to load a template to add `data` from a previous success ajax callback and I solved in this way:

```
var t;
$.get('/js/template/page_01.mst',
    { t: new Date().getTime() }, // I added this var in here
    function(template) { 
        // etc... 
    });
```

But as I said I don't know if it can solve your problem.

In my case the page I was trying to get was cached.